# How can I use the same XML layout for different activities?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making a quiz app which includes 50 different quizzes. I have a basic quiz layout with buttons and text views, and I want to use this layout with all my activities. For example, if the player choose the first quiz, the layout should come automatically and my Java code should provide the corresponding answers/questions. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Put layout id in `setContentView(layout id)` in your activity's `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your other activities just changue your setContentView id like this :-

old contentViewId:-

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourCurrentView);
```

change id:-

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourNewView);
```